# displayName showing null after creating user with Firebase Auth

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to add a user using the Firebase auth and it returns the displayName as null, even though it asks for it via the UI on sign up.  Any ideas why and how to fix?  Here's the code I am using to do this:

```
startActivityForResult( AuthUI.getInstance()
                                            .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                                            .setProviders(Collections.singletonList(new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.EMAIL_PROVIDER).build()))
                                            .build(), RC_SIGN_IN);
```

and in the Activity for Result....

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // user is signed in!

        //save user
        saveUser();

        startMainActivity();
        return;
    }
```

save user code is as follows:

```
private void saveUser(){
    FirebaseUser fUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    final User user = new User();
    if (fUser.getDisplayName() != null) {
        user.setUserName(fUser.getDisplayName());
    } else {
        Log.e("FB_info", "User has no display name");
    }
    user.setUserEmail(fUser.getEmail());

    final DatabaseReference userRef =         FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(FirebaseRefs.getUsersRef()).child(fUser.getUid());
    userRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(!dataSnapshot.exists()){
                userRef.updateChildren(user.toMap());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

Any idea why the display name is returning null?

Comment: I have the same problem and was just about to make a post question about it. Im using android os and "FirebaseUI for Android — Auth" library. The problem is as the OP states: user object returned right after a new user has been registered has null value for displayName() call. However, if you LOGIN (not sign up) again with the same credentials the name field contains the value as expected.

Answer (score 4):

So this appears to be (now known) bug in the Firebase itself (Not Firebase-UI). The bug appears to be introduced with version `Firebase Android SDK v9.8.0`. For the time being one of the workarounds is to force users to **logout and re-login** after they have registered with system. The other involves **downgrading FirebaseUI** to the version which uses older Firebase SDK version.
Source: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/409

Comment: Yes, they emailed me about this after I posted that issue on github.  They are working on a fix, but say that you can download to 9.8.0.   The 10.0.0 version also introduces a bug into the Firebase Auth method as well.  Hopefully they'll fix this soon!  Thanks for the response!

Comment: Now they're saying you need do downgrade to 9.6.1 for play services and Firebase dependencies in order for it to work

Answer (score 0):

You Can Also Get Name From firebaseAuthWithGoogle Method.

```
  private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(final GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
  AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(acct.getDisplayName());
                        System.out.println(acct.getPhotoUrl());
                    }

                }
            }); }
```

Comment: Your method is for getting the credentials from a Google sign in.  I'm using email authentication from AuthUI, so your answer doesn't apply.  Thanks for trying to hep though