# Can I get updated emailVerified without logging out?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have following flow for my sign up process:

1. User fills out details and signs up (gets send verification email)
2. After this user is logged in, but sees a screen asking to for email verification
3. User verifies their email and goes back to app

At this stage how can I get new user data that will have `emailVerified` field without logging user out?

I expected `auth().onAuthStateChanged` to be fired once `emailVerified` changes to true, but that does not happen, nor can I find any refresh function in firebase docs to get this data manually.

Only way I can get that new value for `emailVerified` is by loging out and loging back in, but ideally would like to avoid this.

---

update: this is using JavaScript SDK

Comment: There is a known issue in version 9.8-10.0 of the Firebase SDK for Android that means it only updates the user profile when you sign in. Until that is fixed (I don't know when the release is out), there is no solution. Workarounds: stick to 9.6 or to sign-out/sign-in.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40723639/firebaseusers-profile-is-not-updated and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41651454/update-to-authdata/41652179#41652179

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelenoh my bad, I updated the question this is for latest (3.6.7) javascript sdk

Comment: Ah hold on, that's completely different. Not sure what the case is there.

Comment: Calling `auth().currentUser` also returns old user information after verifying email successfully @FrankvanPuffelen I have to perform page refresh to get new details or re-authenticate

Comment: `currentUser.getToken(true)` makes onAuthStateChanged fire but returned user object still doesn't have updated emailVerified field

Comment: @llja Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on android I did

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.reload().then(() => {
  console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser)
})
```

this returns updated information about the user, I couldn't find this anywhere in the docs for some reason