# Firebase Authentication: get user latest data after login

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I need to get the latest user data like - `emailVerified`, `displayName`, and `profilePhoto`.  User is already logged-in.  I want some sort of event or may be a call to server to see, latest value of user profile data.

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.emailVerified
```

I was trying this, but its returning the value from local (cached values at login), not the latest value from server.
One question is already there, but not answered. :(

[how to get the latest firebase user authentication data from server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61998074/how-to-get-the-latest-firebase-user-authentication-data-from-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the [`reload()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User?authuser=0#reload) method, which is asynchronous and returns a Promise.

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.reload()
.then(() => {
        if (firebase.auth().currentUser.emailVerified) {
            //...
        } else {
            //...
        }
});
```

Comment: thanks,  I tried to find the duplicate questions also. but couldn't.  Thanks for tagging, and answering it.

Comment: hey need help here --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65424508/push-notification-enable-and-disable-by-using-switch