# Email verification not working on Firebase email custom action handler

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I successfully sent a verification email to the client here is the [Sample Email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHqU4.png)

here is my code for the email action handler

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.16.1/firebase.js"></script>


<script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            var config = {
                'apiKey': "my api key here"
            }

            var app = firebase.initializeApp(config);
            var auth = app.auth();

            var mode = "<?php echo $_GET['mode'];?>"
            var actionCode = "<?php echo $_GET['oobCode'];?>"

            auth.applyActionCode(actionCode).then(function(resp) {
                console.log(resp)
                document.getElementById('message').textContent = "Success! Email Verified"
            }).catch(function(error) {
                document.getElementById('message').textContent = "There was an error verifying your email"
            })

        })
 </script>
```

this will print Success! Email Verified

I checked the client account and still its not verified

My question is why clicking the link does not verify the client account?

Comment: How did you check the client account? Keep in mind that this call will not automatically refresh the user profile in your application code. You will need to sign-out/sign-in or [reload the user profile](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#reload) before the update shows up in the client-side code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `auth.applyActionCode(actionCode)` will not automatically refresh the user profile in your application code. You will need to sign-out/sign-in or [reload the user profile](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#reload) before the update shows up in the client-side code.

Also see:

- [Can I get updated emailVerified without logging out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41874910/can-i-get-updated-emailverified-without-logging-out)